# Appending Dictionary to Swift Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I have this Swift code in which I'm trying to append a Dictionary to Array.

```
        var savedFiles: [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] = []
        var newEntry =  Dictionary<String,AnyObject>()

        if let audio = receivedAudio?.filePathURL {
            newEntry["url"] = audio
        }
        newEntry["name"] = caption

        savedFiles.append(newEntry! as Dictionary<String,AnyObject>)
```

This gives me an error on last line (in append) `Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)'`

Any idea? I also tried remove force unwrapping as well.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
var savedFiles: [[String: AnyObject]] = []
var newEntry: [String: AnyObject] = [:]

if let audio = receivedAudio?.filePathURL {
    newEntry["url"] = audio
}
newEntry["name"] = caption

savedFiles.append(newEntry)
```

Comment: I tried that as well, it also give a error 'Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)'

Comment: Did you try using Any instead of Anyobject?

Comment: Try doing var savedFilesDictionary = [String: AnyObject]() instead of var savedFiles: [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] = []

Comment: @natasha If we use as you suggested, we won't be able to use array property of append

Comment: @SachinRocken , yes I did but it gives the same error.

Comment: @natasha tried your suggestion, but it gives same error

Comment: @WarunadeSilva I think you should try like this : var savedFiles: [AnyObject] = []

Comment: @WarunadeSilva could you upload your project with a link to see it myself?

Comment: This solution works for me in the Playground assuming `audio` is `NSURL` and `caption` is `String`.

Answer (score 1):

Hi just tried on playground its working, only you should know this: audio could be nil any time, in that case this key value pair won't be added in newEntryDictionary.

```
var savedFilesDictionary = [[String: AnyObject]]()
var newEntryDictionary = [String: AnyObject]()
var receivedAudio = NSURL(string: "/something/some")

if let audio = receivedAudio?.filePathURL {
    newEntryDictionary["url"] = audio
}
newEntryDictionary["name"] = "some caption"
savedFilesDictionary.append(newEntryDictionary)
```

Answer (score 1):

As of **Swift 4**, the correct way to work with dictionaries:

### Declare empty dictionary (associative array):

```
var namesOfIntegers = [Int: String]()
```

### Append to dictionary:

```
namesOfIntegers[16] = "sixteen"
```

### Check if dictionary contains key:

```
let key = 16
if namesOfIntegers.keys.contains(key) {
  // Does contain array key (will print 16)
  print(namesOfIntegers[key])
}
```

See more, straight from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely no problem:

```
var savedFiles: [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] = []
var newEntry =  Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()
newEntry["key"] = "value"
savedFiles.append(newEntry)
```

Although this is the "Swifty"-Style:

```
var savedFiles = [[String: AnyObject]]()
var newEntry = [String: AnyObject]()
newEntry["key"] = "value"
savedFiles.append(newEntry)
```

I am using Xcode 7.2.1.

Answer (score -1):

```
var savedFilesDictionary = [String: AnyObject]()
var newEntryDictionary = [String: AnyObject]()

if let audio = receivedAudio?.filePathURL {
     newEntryDictionary["url"] = audio
}
newEntryDictionary["name"] = caption

savedFilesDictionary.append(newEntryDictionary)
```

Try this.

Comment: It gives similar error ,  Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '([String : AnyObject])'